# No ASP.NET MVC 5 Partial Page (Razor) in Add >

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm supposed to add an ASP.NET MVC 5 partial page (Razor) to my project, I must do this to create a view called `LatestTweets.cs.html`. When I right-click on Partials > Add > I cannot see any ASP.NET MVC 5 Pages.

[image]

The ASP.NET MVC 5 Partials Pages can be seen here:

[image]

I don't know if I have to install any new packages or if I have the write the code (as below) elsewhere.

```
@model string
<h1>Load the Tweets for the @model</h1>
```

Comment: BTW `LatestTweets.cs.html` should be `LatestTweets.cshtml`